# Android 6 Marshmallow troubles with Spinner on Toolbar

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-6.0-marshmallow

I simply added a spinner with the Toolbar and working fine in all devices of Android up to Android version 5. However when I tested this thing with recently launched Android 6 it's not displaying items in spinner, just blank white background.

What changes I need to make out to resolve this abrupt behaviour. Here below is styles used for this spinner in Toolbar.

style v21 :--

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Spinner" parent="Widget.MyApp.HeaderBar.Spinner">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_language_bg</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/text_color_white</item>
</style>
```

style:-

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.Toolbar.Spinner" parent="Widget.MyApp.HeaderBar.Spinner">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_language_bg</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/text_color_white</item>
</style>
```